# Why "var" keyword sets to certain type?

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

Why `var a = 7;` would set `a` type to a certain type (i.e. `int` instead of `byte`)? Are there any rules/defaults/checks made on the fly by C# compiler?

Comment: It's called [type inference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference).. [MSDN covers it perfectly..](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx).

Comment: I think he's partly wondering why `var a = 7` doesn't declare a as a byte... which is because the C# compiler sees 7 as an int.

Comment: @DaveZych Exactly, you've got me :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by "on the fly" - but the C# compiler simply follows the rules laid down in the spec. For a declaration of the kind:

```
var a = expression;
```

the type of `a` is the type of `expression`. The expression `7` is of type `int`, although it's *also* known to be a constant within the range of `byte`, allowing:

```
byte a = 7;
```

to compile. The *availability* of that conversion to `byte` doesn't change the type of the expression `7` though, so `int` is what the C# compiler uses for the type of `a`.

Note that I'd recommend against using `var` for constants like this. It ends up with code which can get pretty confusing around the boundaries of `int`, `uint`, `long` etc. `var` is meant to help with anonymous types, and also to help make code *more* readable. When it makes code *less* readable, just don't use it.

Comment: I figured it out that i.e. `var x = Some_Type` and the type would be some kind of class which implements all of `Some_Type` interfaces. I might be wrong, but it was my own simple logic. Whole riddle was about numbers, actually... Thanks for making it more clearer, Jon!

Comment: @AdrianK.: The best approach here isn't to guess how a language works - it's to read up on it. Personally I like using the language specification to get the authoritative answer, but of course there are books which can be somewhat less intimidating :)

Comment: Absolutely! :) I was trying to find answer on that in Andrew's Troelsen book which I own and love to read, but I didn't. I aslo didn't got any google query making sense since I don't know English as well as I would like to.

Comment: @AdrianK.: At the risk of sounding commercial, I *know* that C# in Depth explains `var` carefully :)

Answer (score 2):

The compiler treats any integer literal in your code, that does not have a suffix, as an `int`.

So this:

```
byte myByte = 255;
```

..is actually implicitly converting the `int` constant 255, to a byte.

That is why `var` is infered to be an integer.. because the compiler uses integer literals by default.

If you were to do this:

```
var a = 7L;
```

A would be of type `long`.

Answer (score 1):

There are defaults, I couldnt' tell you all of them off hand.  Similar to if you call 5/7 that it defaults to integer division.  but if you do 5/7.0 then it will do regular division.  var just sets the type to be whatever is the type of the assigned value, in your case without a cast it is an integer by default.

Answer (score 0):

`var` does not mean "determine the type at runtime", it means "determine the type using the result type of the expression on the right hand side of the assignment operator."  It is determined at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx):

> An implicitly typed local variable is strongly typed just as if you
>   had declared the type yourself, but the compiler determines the type.

[and](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx):

> The var keyword instructs the compiler to infer the type of the
>   variable from the expression on the right side of the initialization
>   statement.

In plain and simple terms, the compiler will check the lowest available type for the data assigned to the variable and will strongly-type said variable to that data-type.

Answer (score 0):

The var keyword automatically sets the giving value to the type that the compiler can convert. Ex: var s = ""; contains a string and will be made a string.

Answer (score -2):

It sets a to the expression type because var is a general type and since the CLR handles the memory management for you it needs and will determine the type of the expression and make the variable a that type.

Comment: `var` isn't a type at all, and the CLR's memory management is completely irrelevant to this. `var` is a way of asking the C# compiler to *infer* the type for you. It's not the CLR that determines the type - it's the compiler.